# Silverlight cross domain confusion

Tags: silverlight, iis-7, cross-domain

I have a Silverlight application that does two things:

1) connects to a WCF server (hosted inside a WPF app on a different PC) and sends small packets of info (using `PollingDuplexHttpBinding` if it matters)

2) sends a web request for get an XML file from a different remote server for parsing

At dev time, its all running locally, but in production it will be a scattered deployment each running on a different server.

But I am running into issues that I think are related to the `clientaccesspolicy.xml` and `crossdomain.xml` files

My Silverlight app runs at a random port (as defined by VS2010)

The WCF service runs at: http://localhost:80/MyService which I can connect to just fine from the SL client (I have got a `clientaccesspolicy.xml` file on the WCF side)

But, and here is the part that is failing, when I send a request for the XML file, which is http://localhost/MY_TEST_SITE/thefile.xml I get the error:

`The remote server returned an error: NotFound.`

but I put that address into Firefox I can see the XML file no problem. I do have a `clientaccesspolicy.xml` in that location, which I think is correct.

If it was a cross-domain issue should I be getting a security exception here? instead of a not found exception?

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Its ok I figured it out, I had something blocking on port 80, which was causing a whole heap of issues, once I switched that off, it was back to normal